# Can I take a picture using the front camera on Samsung Galaxy Tab (Android 2.2) ?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-2.2-froyo

Can I take a picture from the front camera?

My application has an input form for inventory.
If an user sends a data,
the user's face pic is also sent to the server for authorization / validation.

I will put the app on Samsung Galaxy Tab (Android 2.2).

Is there any way to take a picture from the front camera?

Comment: Officially, it is supported on platform 2.3 (API Level 9). See this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_FRONT

Comment: @Mudassir is there a way to take picture from front camera on android 2.2 or upgrarding my tab to 2.3 is the only way?

Comment: I don't know any way for platform 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2.2

```
    Camera cam = Camera.open();
    cam.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    cam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    Camera.Parameters para = cam.getParameters();
    para.set("camera-id", 2);
    cam.setParameters(p);
```

Comment: error "The method open() is undefined for the type Camera" can you tell me how to use it? or maybe a link?

Comment: This is a static function which [is available since api level 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open())

Comment: how do I detect if the device has a front camera though, like in a condition

Comment: @CQM by getting the [Camera count](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras()) and `if(info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)` where info is a CameraInfo object

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error:

> "The method open() is undefined for the type Camera"

```
import android.hardware.Camera
```

This is instead of

```
import android.graphics.Camera
```

Both are given as options from eclipse only hardware one has open.